# char *ptr ---> New to C

Tags: char-pointer

Declared char array (read-only): 
const char alpha [] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

Given a char pointer called ptr and the alpha array declared above, how would I make ptr point to the letter 'D'?

I think its ---> char *alpha[3]; because its pointing to the third index of the array.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Yes, and I'm very frustrated.

Comment: If this is a homework question, please have a read of the following: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/2641278. Homework questions are OK on this site but you need to follow the guidelines and [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42617428/edit) your question accordingly.

Comment: The key thing you're missing at the moment is: "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first." You've provided zero evidence that you have done so.

Comment: I keep reverting back to... char *alpha[3];

Comment: If you really stuck in getting started, then Stack Overflow is probably NOT the best place to get help for you right now. You should instead have a chat with you're instructor/teacher.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: "I keep reverting back to... char *alpha[3];", OK so that information should be in your question, not the comments, so [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42617428/edit) your question and add that information in and explain yourself as to why you think that this is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

D is 3 index away from starting address of  alpha that is A.

So your pointer should be initialized like this

```
char *ptr = alpha + 3;
```

Comment: That makes much more sense than my answer. I was missing that alpha is A. Thank you!